# EPF Taxable in United States

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement-plan

I have been working with my Employer (a MNC)  in India for last 7 years. In June i will start working in their headquarters in USA. I wish to withdraw my Provident Fund (EPF) but not sure if that would be taxed as ordinary income in USA or is their any treaty that makes PF withdrawals tax exempt.